# Does Windows log the movement of files?

Tags: windows, logging, file-system

If I move a file from a non-hidden encrypted drive to my main C drive, then move the original file to a hidden container on the encrypted drive, then wipe the original file with ccenhancer/secure erase, is that doing enough to ensure the original location isn't known? Or does Windows log moved files by default and someone could tell if the copied file came from the encrypted drive?

Comment: I can't tell you the specifics, but what I can tell you is that Windows essentially tracks and records everything you could possibly do to the nth degree, and stores this information in all sorts of artifacts.

Comment: @johndoe [[Citation needed]]